# Creating Shell in C - Piping and External Commands

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to create a small shell using C. At the moment I am trying to figure out piping and external commands. I got stuck in them both even after looking at various youtube videos.
I referred to MAN and even [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.ir/)

What can I change to improve and make the implementation work?

This a part of the checking of commands, `args := tokenisation by whitespace`, `commLHS := will be used to store args before | and commRHS will be used to store args after |` and  `indexT refers to the number of arguments inputted`

```
else if((check4pipe(args, commLHS, commRHS, indexT) != 0))
    {
        return runPipeComm(commLHS, commRHS);
        //fprintf(stderr, "%s: command not found\n", args[0]);
    }
```

This will execute External Commands

```
void externalCommands(char **args)
{
    // fork-plus-exec pattern 
    // https://www.percona.com/community-blog/2021/01/04/fork-exec-wait-and-exit/

    /*
        First we Fork
        Then we Exec
        Then we Wait
        Then we Exit
    */
    int status;
    
    pid_t pip = fork();

    if (pip == -1) 
    {
        perror("Error - fork()");
    }
    else if (pip == 0) 
    {   
        //If PID is the child process
        //Launches the process.
        
        if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0) 
        {
            perror("Error - execvp()");
        }
    }
    else 
    { //If PID is the parent process.
        //Waits for the child process and returns exit code if waitpid() is successful.
            if(waitpid(pip, &status, WUNTRACED) == -1)
            {
                perror("Error occured during waitpi");
            }
            else
            {   
                //set_exitcode(status); //Sets the exitcode environment variable.
            }
    }
    
}
```

This is to check for | in args inputted by user after tokenisation.

```
int check4pipe(char **args, char **pipeLHS, char **pipeRHS, int indexT)
{
    bool foundPipe = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < indexT; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(args[i], "|") == 0)
        {
            foundPipe = true;

            memcpy(pipeLHS, args, (i+1) * sizeof(char*));
            pipeLHS[i] = NULL;

            memcpy(pipeLHS, args+(i+1), ((indexT-i)+1) * sizeof(char*));
            pipeRHS[i]= NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if(foundPipe == true)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This will run the pipe commands

```
int runPipeComm(char **commLHS, char **commRHS)
{
    int userPipe[2];
    
    pid_t pip1; // Pipe ID 1
    pid_t pip2; // Pipe ID 2

    if(pipe(userPipe) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error Occurred while piping: ");
    }

    // Start Process 
    pip1 = fork();

    if(pip1 == -1)
    {
        perror("Error Occurred while forking: ");
    }
    else if(pip1 == 0)
    {
        dup2(userPipe[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(userPipe[1]);

        //run

        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        pip2 = fork();

        if(pip2 == -1)
        {
            perror("Error Occurred while forking: ");
        }
        else if(pip2 == 0)
        {
            dup2(userPipe[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(userPipe[1]);

            //run

            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(userPipe[0]);
            close(userPipe[1]);

            wait(NULL);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Observation: there is no need to test the result of `execvp()` as in `if (execvp(args[0], args) < 0)`.  If it succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.  You should probably exit after printing the error message too; otherwise, you end up with to processes both thinking that they're the master shell, which leads to chaos somewhere along the line.

Comment: You will eventually need a more robust method of handling pipelines.  There can be many processes in a pipeline — `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` is an example of a common pipeline fragment which takes input from another command before it.  It looks for duplicate lines and counts how many times each occurs.  There could be an extra filter `grep -Ev -e '^[[:space:]]*1[[:space:]]'` to eliminate singletons.  It looks as though your pipe code only handles a single pipe — `lhs | rhs`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to change some things when copying snippets within your program.

wrong:

```
            memcpy(pipeLHS, args+(i+1), ((indexT-i)+1) * sizeof(char*));
            pipeRHS[i]= NULL;
```

right:

```
            memcpy(pipeRHS, args+(i+1), (indexT-(i+1)) * sizeof (char*));
            pipeRHS[indexT-(i+1)] = NULL;
```

wrong:

```
            dup2(userPipe[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
            close(userPipe[1]);
```

right:

```
            dup2(userPipe[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            close(userPipe[0]);
```

After the first `//run` line, add the missing

```
        execvp(*commLHS, commLHS);
        perror("Error - execvp()");
```

After the second `//run` line, add the missing

```
            execvp(*commRHS, commRHS);
            perror("Error - execvp()");
```

Finally, the write end of the pipe must be closed in the parent process, so move the `close()` there:

```
        close(userPipe[1]);
        pip2 = fork();
```